# Bind Values To a comboBox Dynamically

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I am Working On a C# Windows Form.
I have A Combobox In My Windows Form Where I need to Bind Values Dynamically Form Database Accordingly.
With An Example Can Anyone explain Me How To Do It.

Answer (score 4):

Get the Values of the database store them to an array or a DataSet, and by using [`ComboBox.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx) Property you can bind the Combobox dynamically.

**EDIT**

```
 string[] stringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
 comboBox1.DataSource = stringArray;

          OR
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select StdNo,StdName from TempDb", conn);
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter DataA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable DSet = new DataTable();
 DataA.Fill(DSet);
 conn.Close();
 ComboBox1.DataSource = DSet;
 ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "StdName";
 ComboBox1.ValueMember = "StdNo";
```

Comment: Can U Plss Explain With an Example

Answer (score 1):

In a combo box it supports Name and value pair.
You can use.Either

```
combobox1.DataSource  = ds;


combobox1.DisplayMember = "EmpName";


combobox1.ValueMember = "EmpId";
```

or

```
Dim str As String
        str = "Select * from CountryTable"
        ddCountry.DataSource = obj.GetDataSet(str)
        ddCountry.Items.Clear()
        ddCountry.DataValueField = "COUNTRYID"
        ddCountry.DataTextField = "COUNTRYName"
        ddCountry.DataBind()

//GetDataSet is a function which returns a dataset.
```